# String equals "=" on a varchar column breaks after upgrade from Postgres 10.20 to 10.22

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Yesterday I upgraded our Postgres DB from 10.20 to 10.22. I'm using Docker to run the DB, so I just updated the Docker config to run the newer version and kept the same data folder. As far as I know, point releases within the same major version should be backwards compatible. This morning some but not all users started reporting that they couldn't login, and we realized the problem was that for some usernames - type is varchar(48) - we could no longer match on them using "where username = '[the username]'". Strangely, if we do "where username like '%[the username]%'" it works. Also strangely is "=" worked after we downgraded back to 10.20. Did something about varchar change in the newer point release? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: If the patch changed the behavior of the equals = functionality, that would be a bug. I don't have this issue, could you create a complete example of your data including ddl to replay this issue?

Comment: Sounds similar to this thread [Index corruption](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAOQPKavKxwFnRF4-D%2BfZY4%3D%2B4vKW%3Dxi_SKTXpX853zGLt2-Ceg%40mail.gmail.com) on the pgsql-general list. In that the Docker update also changed the OS in the container and the changes in glibc of the OS resulted in index corruption. It would also affect text comparisons like what you are doing. I would read the entire thread.

Comment: For more information read [Locale changes](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Locale_data_changes) on the Postgres Wiki.

Comment: Thank you @AdrianKlaver. Yes I think the Docker OS version changed, and so it might be this problem.

Comment: Hi @FrankHeikens. It is probably the glibc problem Adrian mentioned. I figured it was highly unlikely = functionality changed with no documentation.

Comment: Perhaps you could show what these user names look like. With simple ASCII strings, the sort order doesn't change, which would speak against a collation problem.